SAGA variable buffer not visible in QGIS
I like to use the variable buffer function of SAGA in QGIS. Although I've installed SAGA and it does not appear in the QGIS toolbox. Did I something wrong while installing or is this function renamed or not part of SAGA anymore?


I thought it is not part of QGIS anymore. You have a variable buffer expression, however, to create geometries using Geometry by expression

buffer_by_m see: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#buffer-by-m

You need the Processing Saga NextGen Provider plugin for later versions of QGIS and SAGA.  It's part of the official QGIS plugin repository.

I have installed it via the QGIS plugin and linked the saga file in the settings. Saga does show up after that but it seems not to work and the buffer I was looking for is not there for selection.
